# Retrieve rich text from GridFS with Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am writing a storage for articles and I have decided to use GridFS from MongoDB. I have found and tested some code, but I am not sure that it is a best one. Could you advice me how to make it better?

```
private GridFS gridFs;

public String getPostContent(String name) {
    GridFSDBFile file = gridFs.findOne(name + ".html");
    if (file == null) {
        return "There is no text for this article.";
    }
    return getStringFromInputStream(file.getInputStream());
}

private static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator")).append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null) {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

I will appreciate any suggestions even regarding chosen approach.

Comment: Are you on Java 8?

Comment: Also, are the files expected to be very big, or are they small enough (mostly) to fit in memory?

Comment: Java 7, but it would be great to have ideas for Java 8.

Comment: Files are no more than 1000 lines with 100 symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already on Java 7, you can use [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) on your `BufferedReader` for safe and efficient handling of the underlying I/O resource.

Also, if all you are interested in is to read a file contents as a single `String`, you can consider reading them into a `String`, and then there appears to be three simple ways using either [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/IOExplained), [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) or [Spark (web framework)](https://github.com/perwendel/spark/blob/master/src/main/java/spark/utils/IOUtils.java) libraries:

```
// Guava
String content = new String(ByteStreams.toByteArray(is));
// Apache Commons IO
String content = IOUtils.toString(is, Charset.defaultCharset());
// Spark (web framework)
String content = IOUtils.toString(is);
```

Where applicable, it's recommended to specify the [`Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) explicitly, instead of relying on the [default](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset--).

One difference with this approach is that newlines aren't normalized to `System.getProperty("line.separator")` like what you have done here. If this is crucial for your usage, then a slight refactoring can be:

```
private static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {
    try (InputStreamReader source = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(source)) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        // using for-loop for nicer scoping of 'line' variable
        for (String line = bufferedReader.readLine(); line != null;
                line = bufferedReader.readLine()) {
            if (builder.length() > 0) {
                builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
            }
            builder.append(line);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // recommended to do something about it instead of just printStackTrace()
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Since you also suggest giving ideas about Java 8, you can use [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) as a slightly better replacement - there is no need to handle the appending of [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--) manually:

```
private static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {
    try (InputStreamReader source = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(source)) {
        StringJoiner builder = new StringJoiner(System.lineSeparator());
        for (String line = bufferedReader.readLine(); line != null;
                line = bufferedReader.readLine()) {
            joiner.add(line);
        }
        return joiner.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! You gave me excellent idea to not write this code but to use already written.

Comment: Could you add a way from Spark framework: String content = spark.utils.IOUtils.toString(is) to your answer, please?

Comment: @yarix Updated. :)